# Notification LargeIcon setting on Center position | Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

Below is My Code i set largeIcon in Notification(as in Image below) but icon is not able to set in center of Icon View. I used Below code but has not fixed my error. Thanks in Advance.

```
var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
mBuilder.setLargeIcon(getCircleBitmap(it))
```

=========================

```
private fun getCircleBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(96,96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(output)
    val color = Color.parseColor("#f1f2f5")
    val paint = Paint()
    val rect = Rect(0, 0, 96, 96)
    val rectF = RectF(rect)
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
    paint.color = color
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint)
    paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint)
    bitmap.recycle()
    return output
}
```

[image]